# Why Cluster NodeJS vs Docker, And What About Einhorn?

Tags: node.js, docker

I have been a fan of the ease with which I can create/compose application functionality using NodeJS.  NodeJS, to me, is easy.

When looking at how to take advantage of multi-core machines (and then also considering the additional complexity of port specific apps - like a web app on 80/443), my original solutions looked at NodeJS Cluster (or something like pm2) and maybe a load balancer.

But I'm wondering what would be the downside (or the reason why it wouldn't work) of instead running multiple containers (to address the multi-core situation) and then load balancing across their respective external ports?  Past that, would it be better to just use Einhorn or... how does [Einhorn](https://github.com/stripe/einhorn) fit into this picture?

So, the question is - for NodeJS only (because I'm also thinking about Go) - am I correct in considering "clustering" vs "multiple docker containers with load balancing" as two possible ways to utilize multiple cores?

As a separate question, is Einhorn just an alternative third-party way to achieve the same thing a NodeJS clustering (which could also be used to load balance a Go app, for example)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Docker is starting to take on more and more of the clustering and load-balancing aspects we used to handle independently, either [directly](https://github.com/docker/swarm) or by idiomatic usage patterns. With NodeJS for example, you can have one nginx or haproxy container load balance between multiple NodeJS containers. I prefer using something like fig, and also setting the restart-policy so that the containers are restarted automatically. This removes the need for other clustering solutions in most cases.